# how to openid work with mvc controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I use openid with mvc3/razor.I want to know how do clicking google icon redirects it to google page and again the control returns to the mvc controller?
take example from this site
In short how do jquery we specify in view of a controller getting connected with that controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can Hit controller with Jquery like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/ActionResult",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({parametername: value}),
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    success: function(Result) {
        // $('#usersets').html(Result);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }
});
```